# Translate Relational Algebra to SQL

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Given the following relational algebra statement:

```
id(A) ∪ id(B)
```

Would that be written as:

```
SELECT id FROM A JOIN B ON A.id = B.id:
```

Or am I misinterpreting it?

Comment: Why do you think it is that? Per what reference?

Answer (score 2):

It's a `UNION`, not `JOIN`.

```
SELECT id
FROM A
UNION
SELECT id
FROM B
```